# Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost

Tags: r, plotly

I hava a proplem while use plot_ly 10 times to create 10 surface plots. I get waring:Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost, so plot not show but the first 9 plot can show normally.
warning details：
plotly-latest.min.js:19 WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.
plotly-latest.min.js:36 lost context

Is there a way workaround this proplem?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using new webgl context,reuse previous one.

Remove Context to get rid from it, after using.

gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();